# Does there exist a book on complex analysis with many examples and exercises?

Tags: complex-analysis, reference-request, book-recommendation

> Does there exist a book on complex analysis with many examples and exercises?

I am a student pursuing graduate course in  Mathematics.Our exams are mainly problem based i.e we need to solve problems in a two hour time.So I want a book which has good source of problems

I am learning  Abstract Algebra from Dummit Foote which has so many examples and exercises.In fact everything is said here.

But I am not getting anything like that in Complex Analysis for self study.

I am in need of a book which gives a good concept on the topics,then gives some examples and then gives exercises to solve

There are hardly any examples in books like Conway,Ahlfors,Lang(which are recommended here).The exercises neither contain any hints.

What should I do? Please help.I am feeling puzzled how to start the subject.

Comment: You may want to specify your goal (theory or application?), if you want to get an answer that scratches where it itches :).

Comment: If you are looking into residue theory with applications, [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1799147/191404) may be helpful to you.

Comment: What do you mean by a "goal"?I want to learn complex analysis and that's it@GudsonChou;

Comment: I think Gudson Chou meant: are you looking for a pure mathematics textbook, or for one for engineers or physicists?

Comment: Mathematics for Physics and Physicists by 
Walter Appel has a nice complex analysis part which is in the form you want

Answer (score 3):

Of course:  *Schaum's Outline*.  I think the complex analysis one is by M. Spiegel.  I worked my way through this many years ago.  One chapter a week.  (Until the "evaluate these real definite integrals" chapter, which took longer to do all the exercises!)

Answer (score 0):

I think that "Fundamentals of Complex Analysis with Applications to Engineering, Science, and Mathematics" by  Edward B. Saff  and Arthur David Snider is in the style you are looking for.

Be careful there are couple other books by these authors, and I think that one has a similar title.

Comment: I agree about Saff and Snider.  When a student asks a question like this, I often send them to the Schaum's outlines, which usually cost about $12 and have lots of worked out examples.

Comment: @B.Goddard Personally I prefer Churchil and Brown when teaching complex analysis, but Saff and Snider is more "student friendly".