# Reference for path integrals complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis, reference-request

I'm studying for a test in complex analysis and I'm not confident in complex integration. It would really help if someone could suggest some reference or practice questions(preferably with solutions I can check with) about path integral problems in general and some basic applications of Cauchy theorem

Comment: For quick questions and solutions over a variety of topics, I like using Mathematical Methods in the Physical Sciences by Boas. I think the 3rd edition is the most recent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some problem books in complex analysis I would suggest the following links to go through -

1) [Complex Variable solved problems](http://matematika.cuni.cz/dl/pyrih/complexProblems/complexProblems.pdf)

2) [MSE post having various sources](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1905281/does-there-exist-a-book-on-complex-analysis-with-many-examples-and-exercises)

3)[good complex analysis textbook](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30749/what-is-a-good-complex-analysis-textbook/2142382#2142382)

4) For a good introduction I referred "**A First Course in complex Analysis by Dennis G.Zill**" and for little advanced case i would like to refer "**Complex Analysis by Dennis G. Zill and Patrick Shanahan**".Also many good books by **Churchill & Brown** , another by **Ponnusamy** are also there.

5) [A complex analysis problem book](https://www.maa.org/press/maa-reviews/a-complex-analysis-problem-book)

6) [Complex Analysis Problems](http://www.unibuc.ro/prof/timofte_c/docs/res/2016febComplex-Analysis-Problems.pdf)